# Orchard custom admin page

Tags: orchardcms-1.6

I would like to add a new part to orchard administration area,

I need an iframe in this part, that shows another page in another website.

*page, and other custom content type is not what I need.

Is it possible to create something like that?

Thanks,

NadavSt

Answer (score 0):

Perfectly possible.

You will need a custom module. With a controller called AdminController.

Add a method called Index and a new view in the views folder called Index.cshtml and do whatever you want in there.

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    //do stuff...

    return View();
}
```

Then to create a link to it in the menu, add a file called AdminMenu.cs in the root of your module with something like the following.

```
public class AdminMenu : INavigationProvider
{
   public Localizer T { get; set; }

   public string MenuName { get { return "admin"; } }

   public void GetNavigation(NavigationBuilder builder)
   {
      builder
           .Add(T("My Admin Area"), "4", item => item.Action("Index", "Admin", new { area = "Orchard.MyModule" }).Permission(StandardPermissions.SiteOwner));
   }
}
```

So that creates a item in the menu called "My Admin Area" at position 4 that links to a method called Index in the Admin controller. You can add permissions so the item only appears for those users with that permission. Make sure you protect your action in the controller as well.

I would recommend checking random Core modules to see how they do stuff, it is the best way to see how things work and get examples. Most modules implement the functionality you are after.

Good luck :)

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your answer, i did everything you said.
Now I have My custom module, but how can I use it?
I mean, I need a behavioral for example:
in the left-side menu, i need an access to page, and when I click on that link the page with the iframe should open in edit area.
same behavioral as the blog have.

is it possible?

Comment: How did you create your module? Did you use the Orchard command line? Do you have a Module.txt file in the root of your module? If you do, just go to Modules area and enable your module. The link in the admin menu should be there

Comment: I created my module with orchard command line, and i also have the default generated module txt.
I also enabled my module with the command line, and in admin menu/modules i can see that this module is exist.
but i dont see it as one of the admin menu-items as i wanted.
and idea why?

Thanks

Comment: Have you got the admin menu class?